# How to get content of style and move it to previous?

Tags: jquery

For example, I have:

```
<span class="obfuscate oxy">abc</span>
<style>.oxy::after{content:"n";}</style>

<span class="obfuscate sin">text 1<span class="a">text in span</span>text 2</span>
<style>.sin::after{content:"h";}</style>
```

And want it to to become like this:

```
n
<span class="obfuscate oxy">abc</span>

h
<span class="obfuscate sin">text 1<span class="a">text in span</span>text 2</span>
```

How to do with JQuery?

Comment: Why do you even *want* to use jQuery to move CSS-generated content around? Just use `::before` instead of `::after`.

Comment: I only want the content of the style, not the style itself.

Comment: I don't think I understand that comment; what exactly do you want this jQuery to do? From the question it *looks* like you want to move the generated content from *after* the element to *before* the element..?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use JavaScript (or any client side library) to do this. Pseudo elements `::after` and `::before` are **not part of the DOM** and cannot be accessed with JavaScript.

One alternative would be to change the class (with different pseudo elements) of the elements.

For example:

```
.oxy::after{content:"n";}
.oxyb::before{content:"n";}
```

And then, from JS do: `$('.obfuscate').removeClass('oxy').addClass('oxyb');`